# How to know if someone is embedding my videos?

Tags: wordpress, video, server, network-traffic

I have a centos on Apache webserver where I host some video files. I can access the centos server using root through putty ( Terminal ).

On my wordpress websites, I embed the files using shortcodes.
example:

```
[shortcode]http://website.com/video1.mp4[/shortcode]
```

Today I got an email from my hosting provider that I have used 30TB more than I am allowed to and need to pay like 1000$.

I am sure that this was not from my websites, so I am assuming someone with good site traffic embedded my video as they can see the

> http://website.com/video1.mp4

from the website source code.

I want to know if there is a possibility to know if someone is embedding my videos and thus using the allowed bandwidth.

Thaank you

Comment: -"I have full access to my centos server"_ you mean there's an admin panel where you can see where file-requests / visitors are coming from? How can it shows usage of 20TB but same screen doesn't say access source? Check CentOS documentation for admin panel...

Comment: I meant root access where i can login using putty.

Comment: Just [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44095444/edit) your question to include all relevant info. If asking about root access to Centos then edit it (Why Putty? What you tried that didn't work? What would Putty achieve that your full access to CentOS server cannot do already?)... Anyways right now your question says _"I've got a link like www.mysite.com/video1.mp4 and want to know file access points"_ for that you have to check admin panel then it tells you 100 people came from Facebook (if link was shared there) and 10 more also came from this site (if link was shared here) etc..

Comment: One fast way to see where else your link might be mentioned (if not i-frame) is to use google.com and put link **within quote marks** like this : `"http://website.com/video1.mp4"` then search, now any site whose source code has your link should come up.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a robots.txt that disallows all search engines so I cannot trace using google.

Comment: _"so I cannot trace using google"_ why not? Your robots.txt has nothing to do with stopping Google.com from checking what other pages use your direct video URL in their own links. Get the link directly from your Wordpress _Media_ tab. Then open `google.com` and paste the link but start and end it with quotes. When you search, **any other websites** that has that exact video link will show up (unless they too have a robots.txt to hide their stuff). Also root access only gives you files list. You need the admin panel of your site to check stats.